# Access to undeclared static property: Cache::$_engines

Tags: cakephp, caching

I'm using the cakephp framework with：

```
Config/core.php Configure:: write ('Cache.disable', true);
```

When visiting the website I get the following error. I don't know where the problem is, seeking help

error info：

> Access to undeclared static property: Cache::$_engines in /web/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 510

Comment: If you are not using Cache, then I suggest commenting out any references to Cache within the Core.php file, specially Cache::config()'s. I think Cake will get confused if you leave those uncommented, if you have Cache.disable = true.

Comment: 我已经把core.php中的Cache:config() 注释了，现在还是有问题，不知道哪里的错。 。 %>_<%

Comment: Always mention which version of CakePHP you are using.

Comment: cakephp version 2.4.1